# A file named "XX\Data\AccNum.xls' already exists in this location. Do you want to replace it?

Tags: qtp, hp-uft

Could someone throw some light on here.The below code works absolutely but it keeps bothering me with:

> A file named "XX\Data\AccNum.xls" already exists in this location. Do you want to replace it?

For all rows.

For several times, I'll have to click yes for rest of the code to execute. I've tried `displayAlert=False`, `applicationalerts=false`. no luck.

```
For Iterator = 1 To AccNoRow Step 1

    Set AccNoTB=browser("title:=.*").page("title:=.*").webtable("column names:=;Account No;Account Name;Billing City;Website;Phone;Assigned To;Action","cols:=8")

    'open excel & write to it

    Set Fso=createobject("Excel.application")
    Set file =fso.workbooks.open("XX\Data\AccNum.xls")
    file.worksheets("sheet1").cells(Iterator,3).value=AccNoTB.GetCellData(Iterator,3)
    fso.ActiveWorkbook.saveAs "XX\Data\AccNum.xls"
    fso.quit
Next

Set fso=nothing
Set file=nothing
```

Comment: I figured a part of it. Instead of SaveAs, it suppose to be `activeworkbook.save`. Thank you guys :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution for the problem you "think" you have would be to use `ActiveWorkbook.save` instead of `ActiveWorkbook.saveas`, but the real problem with your code is, that you create a new excel object for every row, this is absolutely not necessary. Just create the object ONCE and save it ONCE after all lines have been added: Saves you a bunch of overhead, speeds up the code and simply is the right way to do this.

```
'open excel & write to it

Set Fso=createobject("Excel.application")
Set file =fso.workbooks.open("XX\Data\AccNum.xls")

For Iterator = 1 To AccNoRow Step 1
    Set AccNoTB=browser("title:=.*").page("title:=.*").webtable("column names:=;Account No;Account Name;Billing City;Website;Phone;Assigned To;Action","cols:=8")
    file.worksheets("sheet1").cells(Iterator,3).value=AccNoTB.GetCellData(Iterator,3)
Next

fso.ActiveWorkbook.save
fso.quit

Set fso=nothing
Set file=nothing
```